# Qt how to extract custom data pointer from QVariant without knowing the internal type

Tags: qt, c++11

I have a `QVariantMap` with data. Inside the `QVariant` I can store **custom class** declared and registered in meta-system.

I know does exists  `QVariant::value<XXX>()` but since i don't know a-priori what `XXX` is I cannot do that.

So I tried to convert to `QObject*` both with `QVariant::value<QObject*>` and `qvariant_cast` but it seems to hold a void pointer:

My attempt:

```
MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue<MyClass*>(obj);  // it works;

qDebug() << variant; // Qvariant(MyClass*,)

QObject* obj2 = variant.value<QObject*>();

qDebug() << obj2; // QObject(0x0)
```

Comment: MyClass inherits from QObject?

Comment: @eyllanesc it does

Comment: I just tried it in Qt 5.11.2 and it works properly: `QVariant(QObject*, QObject(0x55c48a9bfd50))
QObject(0x55c48a9bfd50)`, I could provide a [mcve], 
I do not need to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/44503822/8805095

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QVariant with custom class pointer does not return same address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501171/qvariant-with-custom-class-pointer-does-not-return-same-address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP mentions it works with:

```
QVariant variant(QVariant::fromValue(static_cast<void*>(obj)));
auto test = static_cast<QObject*>(variant.value<void*>());

qDebug() << obj2; // MyClass(0x8a99838
```

As specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44503822/8805095)